# python calculating degree days

Tags: python, r, scipy

I am trying to write a program in python to calculate growing degree-day for a specific insect out of average hourly temperature. The way you calculate growing degree day from hourly temperature is by creating a curve/function out of these discrete values (one value for each hour) usually using interpolation. Then you use min/max temperature threshold where the insects are active to grow and find where they intersect with the created curve/function (the values I am using are threshold_min=11.7C and threshold_max=30C). I am using scipy intepolation package to create a curve out of these discreet values as follow:

```
    x = numpy.linspace(0, 23, 24)
    y_temp = df_temp.loc[pd.datetime(2018, 7, 15)].values

    cubic_spl_temp = scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline(x_spl,y_temp)
```

then I plot this curve with matplotlib, here is what I get:

```
    plt.plot(x, cubic_spl_temp(x_spl))
    plt.axhline(11.7, color='green', lw=2, alpha=0.5)
    plt.axhline(30, color='red', lw=2, alpha=0.5)

image_link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ8YG.png
```

what I need to do is to calculate the area under the curve where the curve and min/max threshold intersect (area between the curve and the two min/max threshold lines).

Is there a scipy function or any other python package that can help me with this? also, is there a way to do it in r which would be easier to do and solve the same problem?

Comment: Help me understand why this isn't a regression analysis problem??? It sure sounds like one and I'm trying to understand what the difference is here (if any).